# WordPress: How do I assign different colors to nav menu

Tags: wordpress, menu, nav

I would like to give my top navigation menu buttons separate colors. For instance, I want the "Home" menu button to have a different color from that of the "About" menu button. Could anyone please assist me with this. My CSS is terrible.

Is there any WordPress plugin that does this.

I hope somebody helps me out. Thanks in advance.

Tomas

Comment: there is no plugin does this, this is too easy to make a plugin. in order to help you, you need to post the link to your site.

Comment: thanx for your quick response. however, I'm still beta testing my site on localhost, since I don't want any major difficulties when we go live. could you explain the process to this scenario? I'd appreciate that a lot. Rgds

Answer (score 7):

If you're using Wordpress menu management you can assign a class to every menu item through the "Menus" option under "Appearance", you just have to create multiple css classes with the desired colors and click the drop-down on the menu item and add it.

```
.red { color:red }
```

[image]

Comment: Is this still the case? I can't find it in WordPress 3.7.1

Comment: Yet again, make sure screen options are set to show this. It wasn't for me - doh!

Answer (score 0):

First, do you know how to open the style.css (or whatever the main CSS file is for your theme).  Once open, add span classes for however many menus items you want to change.  For example:

```
.item-1 {
color:red;
}
.item-2 {
color:blue;
}
.item-3 {
color:purple;
}
.item-4 {
color:orange;
}
.item-5 {
color:green;
}
```

Then, open your page.php (or whatever the main PHP file is) and wrap these CSS span classes around the html for the menu items. Then, you can of course add some simple :hover effects to change the color when the mouse scrolls over.  Just retype the CSS item in the CSS file and add :hover after it.  For example:

```
.item-1:hover {
color:pink;
}
```

So, there ya go!  Hope that helps a bit.  It's always more fun and you have better control of what's around you if you build a site from the core.  Lemme know if you have any questions on that.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use X:nth-child(n) selector.

Just replace "n" with the position of the element and put the type of element you wanna select in place of X.